# how create `custom submit button`? not <button type="submit">

Tags: html, reactjs, submit, react-hook-form

```js
    <Button
        onClick={async (e) => {
          const confirm = await dialog.confirm('Submit?')

          if (!confirm) return

          const event = new Event('submit', { bubbles: true })
          e.target.dispatchEvent(event) // not work
        }}
      >
        Submit
    </Button>
```

Hi.
I want to create `Custom Submit Button` that do another action before `submit`. like above.

but, not work `dispatchEvent`

This method seems to only work with `form` tags....
It's not bubbling from e.target (button)

Is there no choice but to bring the `form` `ref` to `prop`?

Comment: add e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a simple workaround to not override default `onClick`.

I believe you can move your logic to wrapper's `onClick` capture phase and decide there whether to prevent capturing childrens' events:

```js
<div onClickCapture={async (e) => {
  const confirm = await dialog.confirm('Submit?')

  if (!confirm) e.stopPropagation();
}}>
  <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
</div>
```